# "Answer your own question Q&A style"

Tags: discussion, self-answer

So I came up with a question, did my research, and found no help on S.O. Eventually, I did find an answer to the question that I had. Since the question was nowhere on S.O., I figured that I would share my new knowledge with the community since I couldn't find an answer here.

I proceed to write the question and click the little "Answer your own question, Q&A style" box and write my answer.

Immediately, every time I have done this, I get downvotes. Usually the justification is:

> -1 You answered your own question immediately. Why did you even bother to post this?

I figured that since this was made an option, it would be considered appropriate, but every time, I get downvotes.

What does the community think of this feature?

---

I believe this is different from the posited duplicate because the question and answer indicated in that question were downvoted because of poor quality, rather than the explanation I was given in my above quote. I believe (and so do several people [it received several upvotes too]) that the quality of my question(s) and answer(s) were sufficient, yet they were downvoted simply because I did the whole Q&A thing.

Comment: Self-answers should still meet the site quality standards; if it would be a bad question if you needed an answer, being able to provide one doesn't make it acceptable. I'm not a big fan of the (mis?)use of SO just to share your code; if you want to do that, put it on GitHub/BitBucket/etc. However, **if both Q and A would be appropriate from different people, then you should absolutely feel comfortable posting them**. See e.g. the OP's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: People downvoted because they perceived it as a syntax error, not just because it's a self-answer. I agree that it is not the kind of syntax error we should close for though, so your Q+A are both of appropriate quality. The only suggestion I can give is to clean up the title a little bit but otherwise it's just fine.

Comment: Hi @rene downvoting because someone wants to know why his post was downvoted seems strange. Did i miss any irony hints; why would you do this?

Comment: @surfmuggle because it is utter noise but the irony might have gone missing also. Now fixed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Personally, I love the feature.  I think that it's great that you can basically self-answer a question instantly, and it's something that should be encouraged.

The users that vote on these may be upset because, in their mind, they're  not seeing a question *they* can answer too, when that couldn't be further from the truth.  Bear in mind that users will downvote for any reason they feel like, and if the question and answer are on topic, concise, and well-written, it shouldn't have any bearing on your particular question/answer combo.

If it's a good question/answer, don't let it bug you.  If it's not, then double-check to see what you can do to clean it up/make it a bit better.