# Are questions for clarity off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about some topic and I found the answer myself (at least I think so). Would the following be on-topic?

```
How are structures passed and returned by value in the SysV-ABI?
...Some compiler output...
So I come to the conclusion, that structures by value are returned, if they are bigger than 16-bytes in a hidden first argument, else in RAX:RDX.
...Further conclusions...
Am I right or would did I oversee?
```

What should I do?

1. Ask the question, without conclusions and answer it myself
2. Ask the question, like it is above

TL;DR: Are questions asking for clarity about a topic on-topic here?

Comment: What ever you post it needs to be in the Q / A format. So option 2 is out.

Comment: [Should I be able to answer my own question within 12 hours?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293888) AND [Is it right for someone to ask a question for the sole purpose of answering and getting reputation at Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357678) AND ["Answer your own question Q&A style"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290038) AND [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165) AND many others

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should choose the first option: ask the question, and answer it yourself. See [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).